# Mathematica Error: Why does this numerical integration give zero?

Tags: integration, wolfram-mathematica, numeric

I am trying to integrate a function in Mathematica that uses eigenvectors and eigenvalues from a matrix. Using NIntegrate I am getting zero. The error says Eigenvectors: Unable to find all eigenvectors. General: Further output of Eigenvectors::eivec0 will be suppressed during this calculation.

```
\[Gamma]1 = 0.381;
u = 100 10^-3;
\[Phi] = \[Pi]/4;
v = 3 10^-3;
n = 1 10^-3;

H[k_, q_, \[Theta]_] := {
    {u/2, v (k Cos[\[Theta]] + q Cos[\[Phi]] - I (k Sin[\[Theta]] + q Sin[\[Phi]])), 0, 0},
    {v (k Cos[\[Theta]] + q Cos[\[Phi]] + I (k Sin[\[Theta]] + q Sin[\[Phi]])), u/2, \[Gamma]1, 0},
    {0, \[Gamma]1, -(u/2), v (k Cos[\[Theta]] + q Cos[\[Phi]] - I (k Sin[\[Theta]] + q Sin[\[Phi]]))},
    {0, 0, v (k Cos[\[Theta]] + q Cos[\[Phi]] + I (k Sin[\[Theta]] + q Sin[\[Phi]])), -(u/2)}
};

sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk_, \[Theta]_, q_] := Module[{eigenvalues, eigenvectors, eigenpairs},
    {eigenvalues, eigenvectors} = Eigensystem[H[kk, q, \[Theta]]];
    eigenpairs = Transpose[{eigenvalues, eigenvectors}];
    eigenpairs = SortBy[eigenpairs, First];
    {eigenpairs[[All, 1]], eigenpairs[[All, 2]]}
];

Xintegrand[kk_, \[Theta]_, qq_, w_] := (
    4 kk)/(2 \[Pi])^2 (Abs[
        ConjugateTranspose[sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk, \[Theta], 0][[2]][[1]]] .
        sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk, \[Theta], qq][[2]][[3]]
    ]^2 / (w +
        sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk, \[Theta], 0][[1]][[1]] -
        sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk, \[Theta], qq][[1]][[3]] + I n) +
    Abs[
        ConjugateTranspose[sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk, \[Theta], 0][[2]][[1]]] .
        sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk, \[Theta], qq][[2]][[4]]
    ]^2 / (w +
        sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk, \[Theta], 0][[1]][[1]] -
        sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk, \[Theta], qq][[1]][[4]] + I n) +
    Abs[
        ConjugateTranspose[sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk, \[Theta], 0][[2]][[2]]] .
        sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk, \[Theta], qq][[2]][[3]]
    ]^2 / (w +
        sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk, \[Theta], 0][[1]][[2]] -
        sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk, \[Theta], qq][[1]][[3]] + I n) +
    Abs[
        ConjugateTranspose[sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk, \[Theta], 0][[2]][[2]]] .
        sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk, \[Theta], qq][[2]][[4]]
    ]^2 / (w +
        sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk, \[Theta], 0][[1]][[2]] -
        sortedEigenvaluesAndVectors[kk, \[Theta], qq][[1]][[4]] + I n)
);

NIntegrate[Xintegrand[kk, \[Theta], 1, 0.1], {kk, 0, 200}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

Comment: It might be helpful to write out what you are trying to do mathematically using LaTeX, if you know how. Personally, I don't use mathematica, and it's hard to tell if it's the code or the math that's causing the problem.

Comment: In Mathematica decimal constants with only a few digits are interpreted to be machine precision and use the default hardware floating point for calculations. If I change `γ1=0.381` to `γ1=381/1000` and `Xintegrand[kk, θ, 1, 0.1]` to `Xintegrand[kk, θ, 1, 1/10]` and add the option `WorkingPrecision->256` then the error message is replaced with "NIntegrate, slwcon, Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small." So which it is? Why doesn't SO delete all Mma tags?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.